# Exploration time and Forced March

Tags: travel, exploration, pathfinder-2e-playtest

I'm currently playtesting the new Pathfinder 2e rules and preparing for the second adventure of Doomsday Dawn.

**Exploration rules** in that adventure are specifically important, since a big part is **tracking the time the adventurers take to complete their mission**.

I'm clear on the following rules (page references belong to the Pathfinder Playtest Rulebook):

- **Character travel distance** (p.316, 317)

  - **Hourly travel** distance depends on the character base speed (i.e. a character with 30' base movement will travel 3 miles if terrain has no impediments).
  - **Daily travel** distance assumes characters travel 8 hours a day.
- **Resting rules** (p. 332):

  - Characters must **rest once every 24 hours period**. If a character goes for more than 16 hours without going to sleep, he will be fatigued.
  - A character needs a night's sleep to remove the fatigued condition (8 hours of sleep).
  - The time a party spends resting when they're at watch chores increases based on how few characters are taking turns to watch.
- **The fatigued condition** (p. 322) imposes the hampered 5 condition and cumulative penalties for each action the character performs every round. Penalties reset at the start of the character's turn.

So my questions are: **what prevents a party** of, say, four characters **from travelling up to 13 hours a day**, then rest for 10 hours and 40 minutes, and keep traveling at the same pace? **Is there any mechanic I'm missing?** Which one?

From a roleplaying perspective I understand this wouldn't be feasible: a party would have to make camp, wash themselves, feed themselves and their animals... But I cannot find anything in the rules that measures that, and I would like confirmation about that being part of the GM's playbook to do as he sees fit.

What I'm really missing are some **rules related to fatigue and forced march**. For example, in Pathfinder 1e you would have to make Fortitude saves in order to keep travelling for longer than 8 hours or take non-lethal damage and become fatigued. Might I be missing them somehow?

Thanks in advance for your feedback. May your dice roll true!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already the answer in your hands since the game system can't (and don't want to) provide you a table with the distance for every hour marched and put in what want to be a more smoother system too much arithmetics like the previous one (or 3.5 D&D edition).

You have a daily travel entry with a listed distance...if your party wants to travel the entire day...well, at the end of the day, they have traveled that distance.

Remember this is a playtest and rules like forced march are, usually, really specific and situational. Probably, in the final version, the game will have a rule to handle that situation but for now I don't think it's in the playtest (or at least I have not found anything in that regard).

Comment: I have the feeling you are right. Still, I'll live this question open and see if someone else can add something else I've missed so far. Thank you for your prompt answer!

Comment: This makes me think of the point of the playtest (and including this section in the provided adventure): They want to know how these rules feel at the table. Did you feel like the PC's were able to travel too far too fast? Did you feel like they should have been fatigued at that pace? Was everybody happy that they didn't have to roll Constitution and that Endurance isn't a thing anymore?

Comment: That feedback would be certainly useful, if they asked for it.